# qgis2threejs window is blank

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs

I have used QGIS2threejs for several years in QGIS2. Now we have upgraded to QGIS3 at work and the plugin no longer works.

The qgis2threejs window is blank and it displays the error “Any 3D objects not registered. There is a compatibility issue with QGIS 3D view. You need to close QGIS 3D view(s) and restart QGIS to use this preview.”

I have restarted QGIS and restarted my computer and tried to open QGIS2threejs as the first action. Still the same problem.

This page suggests going to view and manually closing any 3D map windows. I have checked this and I do not have any 3D map windows open. 
https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/issues/147

I am using version 3.6.2. I am not able to change my version of QGIS because this is a work computer and I don’t have the permissions.

Any ideas how I can get the plugin to work?

Answer (score 2):

Major changes were made between QGIS 2 and QGIS 3, which made plugins for QGIS 2 incompatible with QGIS 3. The plugin developer must update their plugin to make it compatible with QGIS 3. If they don't, you can't use it in QGIS 3.

Fortunately, there's QGIS3-compatible version of qgis2threejs. All you have to do is update to the new version. (Actually QGIS calls this "upgrading," which is a bit confusing and sounds like you're about to be asked for money. Don't worry. `upgrade = update` evaluates to true.)

1. Open the Plugin Manager window (Plugin menu > Manage and install plugins...)
2. Find the plugin you want to update.
3. Click the "upgrade plugin" button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’ve had to go away this week at short notice, I’ll give your solution a try when I get back. I’ll report back.

Comment: I don't get the option to "Upgrade plugin". My buttons are left to right "Upgrade All", "Uninstall Plugin", "Reinstall Plugin". I have tried both "Upgrade All" and "Reinstall" and I get the same error.

Comment: Well then I'm stumped. I assume you tried unistalling the plugin first, then reinstalling it?